# Insert image in sphinx using napoleon pre-processor

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

Using sphinx 3.1.1, I want to insert an image using the napoleon pre-processor.

It seems that by having the command:
".. image::" in the docstring, it prevents pre-interpretation with the napoleon pre-processor and the docstring is interpreted by the standard sphinx interpreter.

```
"""Func

   Args:
       var1 (number): description 1.
       var2 (string): description 2.

   Returns:
       string: description 3.

.. image:: /_images/test.png
   :width: 100
"""
```

My image is correctly visualized, but parameters and return values are not correctly interpreted, they look like plain text.

[image]

When I remove the image command, I get the expected interpretation:

```
"""Func

   Args:
       var1 (number): description 1.
       var2 (string): description 2.

   Returns:
       string: description 3.
"""
```

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Remark: I don't want to write my documentation in sphinx standard reStructuredText.

Comment: please show the the image of the error

Comment: Please show the text of the error message (please no images of text) by editing your question, as well as the portion of the docstring that throws the error message.

Comment: Done! I hope it is clearer now :). Actually no error involved, just the napoleon pre-processor stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is important. The image directive must be aligned with the other paragraphs in the docstring.

It can look like this:

```
"""Func

   Args:
       var1 (number): description 1.
       var2 (string): description 2.

   Returns:
       string: description 3.

   .. image:: /_images/test.png
      :width: 100
"""
```

Or like this:

```
"""
Func
 
Args:
    var1 (number): description 1.
    var2 (string): description 2.
 
Returns:
    string: description 3.
 
.. image:: /_images/test.png
   :width: 100
"""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried everything with white spaces and yet I missed the most logic solution. Great!